# jQuery, $(document).ready({--}), multiple functions and multiple files

Tags: jquery

I've been noticing some odd behavior when trying to implement a configuration javascript file to enable/disable user interface features based on development or production environment, and can use some clarification.

This is a flat application, and I've split the javascript into three files: index.js, dashboard.js and taxonomy.js.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/taxonomy.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/dashboard.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/index.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/config.js"></script>
```

The index script handles the login, logout and element initialization functionality.  Its defined as

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $.ajax({
    //query db for login
    success : function(){
      loginHandler()
    }
});

function loginHandler(){
  initializeDashboardElements()
  initializeTaxonomyElements()
}
```

Inside taxonomy.js, there is no `$(document).ready()` definition, but `initializeTaxonomyElements()` exists, which applies jQuery UI bindings to the specified HTML elements.  One such element is a tab widget that currently contains 4 tabs, but is expected to grow.

Inside `config.js`, I have this for the production environment:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "disabled", [1, 2]);
});
```

Given this setup, I get an error

```
Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'
```

I've also tried this with `initializeTaxonomyElements()` within a `$(document).ready()` declaration.  The same error occurs.

Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: Where did you initialize the tabs widget? you can't call .tabs("option"...) before the tabs widget is initialized. you simply can't.

Comment: @KevinB, $("#tabs") is initialized within `initializeTaxonomyElements()`

Comment: How is it initialized within that function? after an ajax request? after an animation? after a setTimeout? after some other asynchronous method?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the AJAX call exits immediately (its purpose is to attach the event handler, *not* to wait for the event; the `success` portion of it fires only after the AJAX request is fulfilled by the server). It is almost certain that the function in `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#tabs").tabs("option", "disabled", [1, 2]); });` executes before any initialization in `initializeTaxonomyElements()` takes place.

To fix this, make the call to `$("#tabs").tabs("option", "disabled", [1, 2]);` execute as part of the AJAX `success` method (after `initializeTaxonomyElements()`).